# Can someone translate the following LISP program statement in plain English?

Tags: scheme, expression, lisp, semantics

```
(define substitute (lambda (exp1 var exp2)
  (cond ((atom exp2) (cond ((eq exp2 var) exp1) (true exp2)))
     (true (cons (substitute exp1 var (car exp2)) 
         (substitute exp1 var (cdr exp2)))))))
(define substitute-and-eval (lambda (x y z) (eval (substitute x y z))))
```

I know `eq exp2 var` is checking the memory address for `exp2` and comparing the bit pattern residing there with the bit pattern residing in the memory space of `var`.

But, what is the relationship between `(eq exp2 var)` and `exp1` in the statement `((eq exp2 var) exp1)`?

Comment: "_what is the relationship..._" -- [you need to read about `cond`](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.4.5). `((eq exp2 var) exp1)` is a conditional clause, and `(eq exp2 var)` is a test form. If the test form evaluates to true, the `cond` form evaluates to the expression `exp1`.

Answer (score 2):

```
(define substitute
  (lambda (exp1 var exp2)
    (if (atom exp2)
        (if (eq exp2 var) exp1 exp2)
        (cons (substitute exp1 var (car exp2)) 
              (substitute exp1 var (cdr exp2))))))
```

`substitute` replaces the occurrences of `var` from `exp2` with `exp1`.

However, take into account that this does not make a correct substitution (so the evaluation will return a wrong value), as it does not take into account [name conflicst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_collision) -- it should generate [fresh variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Capture-avoiding_substitutions).

Answer (score 1):

A clearer (IMO) formatting (even if it's not considered "standard"), could be

```
(define substitute 
   (lambda (exp1 var exp2)
      (cond 
         ((atom exp2) 
             (cond 
                 ((eq exp2 var) exp1) 
                 (true          exp2)))
         (true 
            (cons (substitute exp1 var (car exp2)) 
                  (substitute exp1 var (cdr exp2)))))))

(define substitute-and-eval 
   (lambda (x y z) 
      (eval (substitute x y z))))
```

`(cond (test1 body11 ...) ...)` is a conditional, in Scheme.

The clauses `(testN bodyN1 ...)` are considered one by one. If `testN` evaluates to a non-falsy value, the expressions `bodyN1 ...` are evaluated one by one, and the last one's value is returned as the whole `cond`'s value.

Here, as you can see, you have two nested `cond`s. If `(atom exp2)` returns `#t`, `(eq exp2 var)` is considered. If its value is `#t`, the value of `exp1` is returned as the overall expression's (and the function's) value, because each of the `cond`s is in *tail* position.